# SQL - find if a column has more than one distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm going through columns in a large table, and I want to find out if the column has more than one distinct value. I don't care what the values are or how many distinct values there are, I just need to return true if we have more than one distinct value (i.e. two rows with different values for that column) and false otherwise. Performance is my main concern. What's the best way to implement this in SQL?

EDIT: Table has 1M+ rows on MSSQL. The columns have multiple data types; some are nullable and some are not.

Comment: What's a large table for you? 10 million records? More? Less? What server are you using? Oracle? mySQL? MSSQL? Do you have an example row? What data types are you comparing? Lots of unanswered questions on your side...

Comment: Create a unique index on the column or columns you want to check, see if those index fail to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I totally originally misunderstood the question.  You want to know if the values are not all the *same* (the use of the word "distinct" threw me off).

If you want to know that, you can do:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.col <> t.col)
             then 'true'
             else 'false'
        end)
from (select top 1 col from table t) t;
```

The `from` clause chooses an arbitrary value.  The `exists` starts looking for another value and should stop at the first one encountered.  Normally, I would suggest putting an index on the column for performance.